# Solving the energy of the harmonic oscillator using solve_ivp

Tags: python

I had been given the harmonic oscillator equation in the form of : y'' = -w^2 * y with initial conditions y(0) = 1 and y'(0) = 0 and w = 2*pi and I had to compare the analytical solution with the exact solution in the form of y(t) = cos(wt).

So the first part went smoothly and I saw that my result using solve_ivp gives me the exact same curve as the exact solution.
But then I had to compare the evolution of energy for RK45, RK23, and DOP853.
The energy is written : E = 0.5 * k * y^2 + 0.5 * v^2 with k = w^2 and v the velocity v = y'
I was expecting to get a straigh tline, since my harmonic oscillator isn't damped but I got a decreasing curve for each integrations, and I do not know why. If anyone has any idea, I post my code [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha1iH.png). Thanks in advance for the help !

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Exercice 1
#We first write the initial conditions 

omega = (2*np.pi)            
omega_sq = omega**2          
y_0 = [1., 0.]               
t = np.linspace(0, 4 ,100)  #Time interval between 0 and 4 as asked in the problem


def dY_dt (t, y):            #Definition of the system
    solution = [y[1], - omega_sq *y[0]]
    return solution          

result = solve_ivp(dY_dt, (0, 100),y0 = y_0, method = 'RK45', t_eval = t)  

z = np.cos(omega*t)          #Exact solution, for comparison
plt.plot(t, z, 'r', lw = 5)  #Plot of the exact solution
plt.plot(t,result.y[0], 'b') #Plot of the analytical solution


#Exercice 2

def Energie(Y):              #Energy
    k = omega_sq            
    E = 0.5*(result.y[1])**2 + 0.5*k*(result.y[0])**2
    return E

E = Energie(result)

#Legendes
plt.ylabel("Position")
plt.xlabel("Time in seconds")
plt.title('Comparison between analytical and exact')
plt.legend(['Solution exacte', 'Solution solve_ivp'], loc='lower left')

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, E)
plt.show
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Paste it as it is.

Comment: When posting code select and press ctrl + k ot press the {} . Then it is easier to work with. I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this, I hope it is better like that.